# проблема с формой обратной связи на php

Tags: php, html

Учусь верстать сайты, решил сделать форму обратной связи ( ну как сделать, с интернета взять, ибо я полный 0 в php) Мне надо чтобы сообщения отправлялись на почту, а у меня просто выходит ошибка.

```
<?php
$to = 'Maxwowfan@icloud.com';
$firstname = $_POST["fname"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$text= $_POST["message"];
$phone= $_POST["phone"];



$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message ='<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>'.$firstname.'  '.$laststname.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Email: '.$email.'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>phone: '.$phone.'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text: '.$text.'</td></tr>
    
</table>';

if (@mail($to, $email, $message, $headers))
{
    echo 'Заявка успешно отправлена.';
}else{
    echo 'Ошибка';
}
```

[image: Когда нажимаю "Отправить заявку" просто выходит ошибка и на этом все.]

```
<form class="form-area " id="myForm" action="mail.php" method="post">
                            <div class="row">   
                                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                                    <input name="name" placeholder="Введите свое имя" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Введите свое имя'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                                

                                    <input name="subject" placeholder="Имя магазина" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Имя магазина'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                                    <textarea class="common-textarea form-control" name="message" placeholder="Заявка" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Заявка'" required=""></textarea>                     
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="alert-msg" style="text-align: left;"></div>
                                    <button class="genric-btn primary circle" style="float: right;">Отправить заявку</button>       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: А может стоит не блочить ошибку через @, а прочитать, на что там ругается? И записывать результат работы в переменную, и смотреть, что приходит в ответ?

Comment: Я ведь написал, что в php полный 0, а сам код просто скопировал, по этому я и обратился сюда, чтобы не совершать таких ошибок) если ты покажешь на мою ошибку, я буду очень рад и признателен)

Comment: Ну вот сделать то, что я выше написал. И прочитать, что вообще значит @ в PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`@` в PHP значит блокирование ошибок. Не знаю что вы там отправляете, но у вас вообще не совпадают те данные что вы обрабатываете в обработчике и те данные которые заполняются в форме, обратите внимание на `name` ваших input-ов. В форме вы даете пользователю заполнить `name`, `subject` и `message`, но при этом в обработчике у вас откуда-то взялся `fname`, `email`, `phone`. Ну например немного изменим код вашего обработчика формы чтобы он соответствовал самой форме, в качестве простого примера подойдет:

```
<?php
// Проверим заполнены ли обязательные поля, так как все ваши required можно удалить в инспекторе.
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
    // Для начала сохраним данные в переменные, при этом предварительно очистив их, подробнее https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php и отдельно посмотрите типы фильтров https://www.php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.php
    $name    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $text    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Имейте ввиду, что данные можно обработать и иначе, но Вам всегда нужно обрабатывать входящие данные и Вы никогда не должны доверять пользователю, так же можно было очистить ваш $_POST['some_field'] обернув его в strip_tags(), например, есть различные варианты.

    $to       = 'Maxwowfan@icloud.com';
    $subject  = "Тема письма: $subject";
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $message  ='<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>' . $name . '</td> // в Вашем примере есть $lastname но такой переменной у Вас же не существует.
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Name: ' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Subject: ' . $subject . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message: ' . $text . '</td></tr>
    </table>';

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if($success) {
        echo 'Заявка успешно отправлена.';
    } else {
        echo error_get_last()['message']; // Ваше сообщение об ошибке https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-get-last.php
    }
} else {
    echo 'Пожалуйста, заполните обязательные поля формы.';
}
```